# Perl regular expression: How to ignore '..' and 'Rollback' sub-directory

Tags: regex, perl

I would like to ignore '..' and 'Rollback' sub-directory but following code is not working. Please suggest.

```
if(-d $input) {
    opendir (my $dh, $input) or die "Cannot opendir $input: $!";
    while (my $dir = readdir($dh)) {
        my $path_dir = File::Spec->catfile($input, $dir);
        next unless (-d $path_dir && $dir =~ m/^(?![\.{2}|Rollback])/);
        print "dir=$dir\n";
    }
}
```

Output shows only one sub-directory but the desired output should be a sub-directory plus '.'

Comment: Why not simple `next if $dir =~ /^(?: \.\. | Rollback )/x` ... ? (Also skip `\.`)

Comment: I mean `next if not -d $dir or $dir =~ /^(?:\.\.|Rollback)|\.$/;`. If the directory to skip is named _exactly_ "Rollback" then it's `/^(?:\.\.?|Rollback)$/;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely you want to use "non-capturing identifier" ?:
Please try the following code.

```
if(-d $input) {
    opendir (my $dh, $input) or die "Cannot opendir $input: $!";
    while (my $dir = readdir($dh)) {
        my $path_dir = File::Spec->catfile($input, $dir);
        next unless (-d $path_dir && $dir =~ m/^(?:([\.]{2}|Rollback))/);
        print "dir=$dir\n";
    }
}
```